# How do you display a simple text array in Drupal 8 twig?

Tags: drupal-8

I have a content type that specifies a formatted-text array called Soup. It's unlimited.

In twig, is there a shorthand to display under the for block?

```
This shows all 3 nodes.
{% for soup in content.field_soup['#items'].getValue() %}
    {{soup.value}}
{% endfor %}



This shows ONLY the first node. What am I missing here?

{% for soup in content.field_soup %}
    {{soup.content}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This -->>>

{% for item in content.field_soup if key|first != '#' %}

{{ item }}

{% endfor %}